# vue - how to make gap between flex item in Slick-carousel

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my current Slick Carousel.
There are 4 items in a row, and I want to add margin between each item without changing current `aspect-ratio: 1.3/1;`

I find that I have difficulty to override the `vue-slick-carousel` classes. Is Anyone know how to do it?

[image]

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="slick">
    <VueSlickCarousel
      v-bind="{
        arrow: true,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        touchThreshold: 5,
      }"
    >
      <div class="slick-item">1</div>
      <div class="slick-item">2</div>
      <div class="slick-item">3</div>
      <div class="slick-item">4</div>
      <div class="slick-item">5</div>
      <div class="slick-item">6</div>
      <template #prevArrow="">
        <button class="arrow-btn">
          <img src="@/assets/images/common/arrow-right.svg" alt="arrow-left" />
        </button>
      </template>
      <template #nextArrow="">
        <button class="arrow-btn">
          <img src="@/assets/images/common/arrow-right.svg" alt="arrow-left" />
        </button>
      </template>
    </VueSlickCarousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueSlickCarousel from "vue-slick-carousel";
import "vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css";

export default {
  components: { VueSlickCarousel },
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
// override default class

.slick-slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.slick-item {
  aspect-ratio: 1.3/1;
  max-width: 280px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.arrow-btn {
  border: none;
  img {
    height: 40px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-leftpad-ti367?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [examples on the npm package itself](https://gs-shop.github.io/vue-slick-carousel/#/example/multiple), spacing between slides are achieved by wrapping each slide with an additional `<div>` element and then adding margins to the inner one.

Your best bet is to update your DOM as such, by wrapping your `.slick-item` element with an additional `<div>`:

```
<div><div class="slick-item">1</div></div>
```

Then in your CSS it is a matter of adding an arbitrary horizontal margin, e.g. `margin: 0 5px` to achieve a 10px spacing between each slide:

```
.slick-item {
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  aspect-ratio: 1.3/1;
  max-width: 280px;
}
```

See proof-of-concept example: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-bas-b78ke?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue